# How to create a build folder in node js application

Tags: server, build, hosting, nodejs-server

I want to create a build folder for my Node.js application, allowing me to run it on an IIS server without specifying the full project path. Similar to how builds are generated in React.js, I am seeking guidance on creating a build for my Node.js application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnERU.png)
I have a project with a specific structure, and I aim to create a build folder. It's important to note that I'm not utilizing TypeScript in this project. Could you please guide me on the appropriate steps to generate a build for this Node.js project?